# MVC: Razor: Bind SelectList's SelectedValue to textbox

Tags: javascript, razor

I have a model and a View with a select and a few text boxes. I am trying to bind the textbox values to the selected list item the following way:

Model:

```
public class Items
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public SelectList ItemList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListData> MiscList { get; set; }
}

public class SelectListData{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address{get; set;}
    public string City{get; set;}
    public string State{get; set;}

}
Controller:
```

Controller:

```
public async public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    Items viewModel = new Items();
    
    List<SelectListData> tempLIst = new List<SelectListData>();
    tempLIst.Add(new SelectListData() { ID = "1", Name = "ID-1", Address="123 AVE", City = "New City", State = "CA"});
    tempLIst.Add(new SelectListData() { ID = "2", Name = "ID-2", Address="234 AVE", City = "New City", State = "CA"});
    tempLIst.Add(new SelectListData() { ID = "3", Name = "ID-3", Address="345 AVE", City = "New City", State = "CA"});
    tempLIst.Add(new SelectListData() { ID = "4", Name = "ID-4", Address="456 AVE", City = "New City", State = "CA"});
    
    
    viewModel.ItemList = new SelectList(tempLIst, "ID", "Name", 2);
    viewModel.SelectListData = tempLIst;
    return View(viewModel);
}
View:

@Model Items
<div class="form-group">

    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Account</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="input-group col-lg-10">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>

            <select asp-for="ID" asp-items="@Model.ItemList" class="form-control" onchange="OnSelectedIndexChanged_01(this)"></select>                
        </div>
        @{                 
            if(Model.ID != null) {
                var selectedAddress = Model.MiscList.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == Model.ID).Address;
            }
        }
        
        <div>
            <input id="selAddress" value="@selectedAddress" />   =====? how do I set the value to selectedAddress here?             
        </div>
        

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function OnSelectedIndexChanged_01(value, jsdata) {
        var selectedID = value.options[value.selectedIndex].value;
    var selectedText = value.options[value.selectedIndex].text;
    var myArray = [];
    var jsdata = @Json.Serialize(@Model.MiscList.ToList()); ===? this is being assigned correctly
    //myArray = JSON.parse(jsdata); ===> this line throws "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"; commenting this worked out
    //myArray = jsdata;
    console.log("[" + selectedID + "] [" + jsdata + "] [" + myArray + "]"); ===> this line is printing [[object, object], [object, object], [object, object]]
    //console.log("[" + selectedID + "] [" + jsdata + "]");
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].ID == selectedID) {
            var Address = document.getElementById("selAddress");
            Address.value = "";
            Address.value = myArray[i].Address.toString();
            break;
        }
    }
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to bind the selectedValue of the dropdown to a selected Address. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
As ScareCrow indicated, I am able to bind the initial values.
ANother question: my javascript doesn't seem to populate the address text based on the OnChange event of the dropdownlist. I am not sure if I am passing the model's arraylist properly. Any pointers is helpful.

Thanks
NH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Result added]Please try the following code Snippet in view: made changes in your code

```
 @model Items; 
 @{var selectedAddress=string.Empty;}
<div class="form-group">

    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Account</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="input-group col-lg-10">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>

            <select asp-for="ID" asp-items="@Model.ItemList" class="form-control"></select>                
        </div>
        @{                 
            if(Model.ItemList != null) {
                 selectedAddress = Model.MiscList.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == Model.ItemList.SelectedValue.ToString()).Address;
            }
        }
        
        <div>
             <input id="selAddress" value="@selectedAddress" />   

        </div>
        

    </div>
</div>
```

I believe the selected items you set in

```
if(Model.ItemList != null) {
                 selectedAddress = Model.MiscList.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == Model.ItemList.SelectedValue.ToString()).Address;
            }
```

rather than Model.ID in your code.

Dropdown change event can be achieved by the following Javascript code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ID').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            var misclist = @Json.Serialize(@Model.MiscList.ToList());
            for(i=0;i<misclist.length;i++){
                if(misclist[i].id == selectedValue) {
                    $('#selAddress').val(misclist[i].address);
                    break;
                }
            }
            
         });
     });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code helped in displaying the initial values. Now, I need to implement OnChange event for the dropdownlist to populate the values.

Comment: Updated the answer with the Dropdown change event. Try that if it's useful for you @SoftwareDveloper Please keep <select asp-for="ID" asp-items="@Model.ItemList" class="form-control"></select>   this as it is and add the javascript code in the <script></script> part.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am trying to use your code and when I tried displaying the contents of the miscList, I get [[object, object], [object]] instead of the actual values.

Comment: @Json.Serialize(@Model.MiscList.ToList()) is this did?  <select asp-for="ID" asp-items="@Model.ItemList" class="form-control"></select> Hope this also the same. No change.

Comment: Hope you are not changed any other code in controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218764/discussion-between-scarecrow-and-softwaredveloper).

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 issues with my question. @ScareCrow provided a solution to my first issue and helped me in figuring out the solution to my second issue. Here's an updated javascript function(with the key values being lower-case):

```
function OnSelectedIndexChanged_01(value, jsdata) {
    var selectedID = value.options[value.selectedIndex].value;
var selectedText = value.options[value.selectedIndex].text;
var myArray = [];
var jsdata = @Json.Serialize(@Model.MiscList.ToList()); 
//myArray = JSON.parse(jsdata); ===> this line throws "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"; commenting this worked out; jsdata is already a javascript object
myArray = jsdata; 
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].id == selectedID) {
        var Address = document.getElementById("selAddress");
        Address.value = "";
        Address.value = myArray[i].address.toString();
        break;
    }
}
}
```